# Move specific array elements to the end - java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The actual program is slightly different and more complex but to make it simple:

Let's say I have an array consisting of strings. The strings could be animal names or bird names. The strings are all mixed up and there is no particular order in place.

I need to make sure that animal names are displayed first and bird names second. No alphabetical ordering necessary.

**Assume that I already have the list of bird names that need to be moved to the end.**

Can anyone please help me with a quick and effective way to achieve this in Java?

```
BEFORE:
Cat
Crow
Dog
Cow
Parrot

AFTER:
Cat
Dog
Cow
Crow
Parrot
```

Existing code is something like this:

```
mixedArray

for (each element in the mixedArray){
    //do some processing
    ..
    out.write(mixedArray[x]);
}
```

Comment: How are you differentiating the animal and bird names. We as humans can differentiate them, but how would the computer know?

Comment: So how do you know if a string is a bird or not, do you have an array with all bird names or something in it too? Or is it always just parrot and crow?

Comment: @Expressions_Galore OP say `Assume that I already have the list of bird names`

Comment: if u can use an extra array:traverse the input array index by index and if its a bird copy ito second array into front and move front index by 1 else copy into back index and move back index by 1                  i.e [bird,animal,annimal,bird]=1) [bird, , , ,] 2)[bird, , ,ainmal]3)[bird,,animal,animal] 4)[bird,bird,animal,animal]

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
int begin = 0;
int end = mixedArray.length - 1;
String[] sortedArray = new String[mixedArray.length];

for (String mixed : mixedArray) {
    for (String bird : birdArray) {
        if (mixed.equals(bird)) {
             sortedArray[end--] = mixed;
        } else {
             sortedArray[begin++] = mixed;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `sortedArray` is where we'll store the sorted result, `begin` is the starting index of sorted array and end is the last index. `birdArray` is the array containing the list of bird names. I haven't tested this code but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways to do this.

1. same as Kaushik Sivakumar's comment
2. if you don't want to deal with copying/moving of arrays, use 2 for loops with if condition.

> for(each element){check if not bird then print out}
>
> for(each element){check if bird then print out}